# Can we use the Stack Overflow design/UI components someplace else?

Tags: discussion, design

I am working on a Q&A site, and I am inspired by a few UI components in Stack Overflow. Can we use the Stack Overflow design/UI components someplace else? If yes, are they available in some repository?

Comment: No, they are not available, and the footer of the site states: *site design / logo © 2017 Stack Exchange Inc*, so no, you can't use those some place else without explicit permissiong from Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance